# Image overflowing parent container in Firefox after jQuery scrollbar added

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'll try to keep this as succinct as possible...

I have a image that I had setup to fill it's parent div horizontally and scroll vertically.

I've since added a jQuery based scrollbar to replace the native scrollbar for non webkit browsers.  Since doing so, my image is overflowing it's parent horizontally in Firefox.  Chrome and IE are not having the issue.

It's a little convoluted because I'm using skelJS to set container sizes based on breakpoints, but I don't think that should make a difference.  The parent and child containers along with the image have width's set.

I'm going to post the HTML and CSS first and see if there's something obvious I'm overlooking.  The jQuery targets the .scroll-pane2 class and is working fine beyond my overflow problem.  I'm happy to post that code if there isn't something obvious that I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for the help!

A summary of the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="8u tasting-menu">                           
    <header>
        <div class="scroll-pane2">
            <p>Scroll or click for full-size menu</p>
            <img src="images/bwh-tasting-list-png.png" class=""/>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
     width:100%;
     }

img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    }

.8u {
    width:66.6%;
    height:auto;}

.scroll-pane2 {
    height:27em;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

.tasting-menu img {
    width:98%;
    height:auto;
    }
```

The jQuery based skelton I'm using accounts for the .8u.  I've used it quite regularly and never had the issue, but I'll definitely take another look at it.

I tried the overflow-x:hidden to no avail.  The jQuery scrollbar I'm using overrides the overflow in the scroll-pane2 class.

I need to relook at the scroll bar script I'm using... because before installation, it worked fine, albeit with the Firefox native scrollbars.

I'll try to put a jsfiddle together.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a jsfiddle. Meanwhile, trying adding 'overflow-x: hidden' to your img css.

Comment: I don't know if that's 100% the issue, but I'm betting your 8u class is the culprit. You can't have classes starting with numbers, hence your .8u class is the same as non-existing. EDIT: in fact you can use digits, but you have to escape them

Comment: also, you can use it like this: [class='.8u']